# How to use shadowsocksR in archlinux?

Tags: linux, proxy, archlinux

I use shadowsocks in linux for a while, but recently it become unstable.
In my windows 10 and android, I use SSR normally, but I try to find and install SSR in archlinux, only 'aur/shadowsocksr-libev' can be found and installed. BUT I don't know how to use it.(I use shadowsocks by 'systemctl start shadowsocks@config').
anybody can help me? OR can provide other SSR package in linux?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you use Arch Linux, the official documents seem short of information about it. I am not familiar with Arch Linux, cannot provide much details.

Anyway, as you seems successfully installed shadowsocksr-libev service, try to apply your own SSR configuration(On CentOS/Debian, it's user-config.json), then restart the service and you should be good to go. Here is some information about Arch Linux service may be useful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd

Answer (score 0):

[ssr-python](https://github.com/shadowsocksr-backup/shadowsocksr) contains both client and server.

1.download from github

```
git clone https://github.com/shadowsocksr-backup/shadowsocksr.git
```

2.create your config file like this

```
{
    "server":"YOUR_SERVER",
    "server_ipv6": "::",
    "server_port":YOUR_SERVER_PORT,
    "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
    "local_port":1081,
    "password":"YOUR_PASSWORD",
    "timeout":300,
    "udp_timeout": 60,
    "method":"rc4-md5",
    "protocol": "auth_sha1_v4",
    "protocol_param": "",
    "obfs":"http_simple",
    "obfs_param": "",
    "fast_open": false,
    "workers": 1
}
```

I put the repository in `$HOME/bin/` and config file as  `$HOME/.config/ssr/test.json`, so I use this command to run

```
sudo python $HOME/bin/shadowsocksr/shadowsocks/local.py -c $HOME/.config/ssr/test.json
```

python2 works too

BTW v2ray is another choice